# Jest: Cannot read property then of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have situation in my unit test case for a react application, where in a function calls for another function received in props from parent component. The parent component functions definition is something like this:

```
onSavePropClick(action) { 
    const save = this.saveProperty(action);
    if(action === SAVE){
        return () => new Promise(() => {
            resolve(this.calculate().then(save));
       });
    }
return save;
}
```

This function call has been passed as props to the child component as

```
<MyComponent finalSave={this.onSavePropClick(SAVE)} onClose={()=>this.setState({closeWindow: true})} />
```

MyComponent has a function:

```
savingAndShowResults() {
const { finalSave, onClose } = this.props;
finalSave().then(() => {
onClose();
});
return true;
}
```

Now when I have a test for the  executed, it throws me error as  “Cannot read property then of undefined”, the test is as follows

```
const initialProps={
finalSave: jest.fn(),
onClose: jest.fn()
};

it(‘should handle saving and show results’, () => {
const component = shallow(
<MyComponent {...initialProps} />
);
component.instance().savingAndShowResults();
expect(initialProps.finalSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(initialProps.onClose).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I am not able to figure out why even on resolving in return in promise of Parent component’s function, gives me this error.

Comment: Please update your code to include `initialProps`, it's difficult to know what's wrong without it.

Comment: Done please check

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming `initialProps.finalSave` is a mock function, you need to make sure you're returning a promise from `initialProps.finalSave`:

```js
const initialProps = {
  finalSave: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
  ...
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, I did missed that part, i didnt returned promise, but when I did it I am encountered with other error saying “Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called” for onClose test line

Comment: I have updated my question with the use of onClose as well, as after implementing mockImplementation on finalSave new error is mentioned on onClose test

Comment: I figured out, since the onClose was supposed to be called under “then” of finalSave hence I used setTime out of 5000 to trigger onClose